# Split node edit tab in several tabs with panels (or programmatically)

Tags: commerce, panels, routes, chaos-tool-suite

I have a content type with many fields, so that loading `node/%node/edit` is a pain ! In order to split node edit form **in smaller forms** (menu tabs), I used Page Manager.

### What I did so far

1. Enable the *Node add/edit form* coming with Page Manager, with selection rule *node being edited is from foo_type*
2. Add three new custom panels pages in `admin/structure/pages`, with paths `/node/%node/photos`, `/node/%node/prices`, `/node/%node/fd` ; with selection rule *node being edited is from foo_type*
3. Define its menu as local menu tab.
4. Share *foo_type* fields between these forms, and add a submit node form to each.

**This renders correctly three node edit forms accessible in new local task menu tabs :**

[image: created node edit menu tabs]

### The buggy part

If I edit the node from any of these forms :

- the fields present in it are saved
- the data from other fields saved before is still in the database, and also readable in the form fields if I show up the other forms (except for pictures), but it **is not displayed anymore in the node.**

As per [@Letharion comments](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82272/is-there-an-equivalent-of-view-modes-for-form-editing#answer-90657) : " *[...] while Panels happens to let you output only half the form as well, that is not supported by form api. One way or another, every field must be present. If not, form api will interpret it as "the user deleted the content of those fields" [...]*

## The question

I'm searching a way to patch the current solution, or a fully programmatic way to split node edit into tabs. Thanks for your contribution!

## Edit:

Most of the issue is solved thanks to [flexiform](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/162914/split-node-edit-tab-in-several-tabs-with-panels-or-programmatically#answer-163444), except for inline entity commerce products. So I'm trying with MrD answer for this specific field, as exposed below.

The commerce product is saved (corresponding DB tables `commerce_product`, `field_data_commerce_price` and so on have a new record), but not attached to its product display (and no record in `field_data_field_product`). No error is returned.

**How to correctly save that commerce product so that it is attached to its node display ?**

```
function vts_nodedit_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['node/%node/prices'] = array(
    'title' => 'Prix et dates',
    'page callback' => 'node_page_prices',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'node_access',
    'access arguments' => array('update', 1),
    'weight' => 4,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'context' => MENU_CONTEXT_PAGE | MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE,
  );

  return $items;
}

function node_page_prices($node) {
  $form = drupal_get_form('vts_nodedit_form', $node, 'field_product');
  return $form;
}

function vts_nodedit_form($form, &$form_state, $node, $field_name) {
  $form = array();
  field_attach_form('node', $node, $form, $form_state, NULL, array('field_name' => $field_name));
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save')
  );
  return $form;
}

function vts_nodedit_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $node = $form_state['build_info']['args'][0];

  //retrieve commerce product to be saved... NON DRUPAL way... :(
  $item = key($form_state['inline_entity_form']);
  $entities = end($form_state['inline_entity_form'][$item]['entities']);
  $product =$entities['entity'];//this is the correct product entity
  //SAVE THE COMMERCE PRODUCT
  commerce_product_save($product);
  //MrD solution 
  field_attach_submit('node', $node, $form, $form_state);
}
```

Comment: if you're not afraid of it using JS, I have done exactly this using the standard edit page, but split up using JS after the fact - since it is displaying the whole, it degrades nicely (or atleast it is still usable) if JS is turned off, just not as pretty

Comment: @Geoff, thanks. My main pb is the _loading charge_ of all these filtered HTML fields and so on... My very first try was indeed to modify the form with JS (could be done also as per Goku answer this way), but this _adds_ loading time instead of reducing it... This is why I need real splitting, not _fake_ ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to use [`field_attach_form`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_form/7)

You can see my example below

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu();
 */
function foo_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['node/%node/settings'] = array(
    'title' => t('Settings'),
    'page callback' => 'node_page_settings',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'node_access',
    'access arguments' => array('update', 1),
    'weight' => 0,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'context' => MENU_CONTEXT_PAGE | MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE,
  );

  return $items;
}
//You can replace body with your field name
function node_page_settings($node) {
  $form = drupal_get_form('foo_form', $node, 'body');
  return $form;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form();
 */
// Have default value if node exit data
function foo_form($form, &$form_state, $node, $field_name) {
  $form = array();
  field_attach_form('node', $node, $form, $form_state, NULL, array('field_name' => $field_name));
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save')
  );
  return $form;
}
/**
 * Implements hook_form_submit();
 */
function foo_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $node = $form_state['build_info']['args'][0];
  //common fields case
  field_attach_submit('node', $node, $form, $form_state);
  //add this for inline entity multi-values fields case (eg commerce products)
  $item = key($form_state['inline_entity_form']);
  $entities = $form_state['inline_entity_form'][$item]['entities'];
  $product = array();
  foreach ($entities as $key => $entity) {
    $product[$key] = array(
      'product_id' => $entity['entity']->product_id
    );
  }
  $node->field_product_store['und'] = $product;
  node_save($node);
}
```

Comment: I don't know many module. So I often code for my feature. In this case you can use my code. I tested my code with Inline entity form. It's ok. With submit function function foo_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  $node = $form_state['build_info']['args'][0];
  field_attach_submit('node', $node, $form, $form_state);
}

Comment: Can you say your url when you submit? And you can check function vts_nodedit_data_submit was called. You try use dpm($node) after $node = $form_state['build_info']['args'][0]; and click submit. Ì you see message say to me. The last, you can replace with $node = node_load(arg(1));

Comment: Thanks. I already did these steps yesterday. Indeed `vts_nodedit_form_submit` is fired, and `$node` is correctly retrieved by `$form_state['build_info']['args'][0]`, not by args[1]. And I stay on the same url `node/%node/prices` which I declare in hook_menu, but I don't think this has an effect, I could redirect either to node/%node

Comment: Your mind is that everything works? Only after submited you can't redirect either to node/%node?

Comment: Sorry if I was not reactive, out of office till now. It is enough to add `drupal_goto( 'node/'. $node->nid )` at the end of the submit fn, tested. But I really don't understand why you focus on redirect? What's working : the commerce product is saved. What's not : it is not attached to its node display, so it is useless. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I have exactly the same, except field_product is a **multi value** inline entity form.

Comment: I was tested with new code. You can see above. It's good.

Comment: I think I got it !!!! Going to clean workspace and make some more tests, but this is it I believe ! I'll let you know tomorrow. Hardly earned bounty !! Many thanks again. Where are you from?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have done a lot of work already, and this continues to be a learning experience.  Since the form is now managed how you want it and it is only the data management in the save process that is causing you trouble, I would suggest a few code additions.  Using hook_form_ID_alter there are two methods you can try.

**Method 1** Add a custom validation callback to the form.

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'MYMODULE_node_data_validate';
```

Then in your new validation function I suggest loading the node ($node = node_load(nid);) and propagating the data into the form_state.  I am not sure this will work, but I have it listed as method 1 because it is the less disruptive path of the two that I have in mind at the moment.

**Method 2** Replace the submit handler with your own.  Similar to the validate function mentioned above, the idea here is to load the node to get the data that was not present on the form that you edited.  However, this time you are going to invoke node_save yourself.  Also you will need to end with a drupal_goto or some other method of sending the user someplace.  Yes you could add an additional handler to the #submit array in the form variable, but either it will be too late to prevent the change the form is doing or it would just be a different name for method 1.

```
function hook_form_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['#submit'] = array( 'hook_something_submit');
}
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter();
 */
function vts_nodedit_form_accompagn__node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['#submit'] = array( 'vts_nodedit_data_submit');
}

function vts_nodedit_data_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // possible cause of missing data is that the form build populates
  $original = node_load( $form_state['node']->nid );

  // this drupal core function does the work of a full node edit save
  // but we have to have the node to hand it
  // and I do not trust all of $form['node'] in your instance
  field_attach_submit('node', $original, $form, $form_state);

  drupal_set_message(t('The changes have been saved.'));

  if( isset( $form_state['redirect']) ){
    drupal_goto( $form_state['redirect'] );
  } else {
    drupal_goto( '/home' );
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
The difference between form_state['input'] and form_state['values'] is that input is the raw $_POST from the user.  I think it would be a security concern to use that directly.  The other validators that are running (why we use $form['#validate'][] and append instead of replace) are taking the new data from input, cleaning it, and putting it in values.  Then if there are blank spots, they fill values with #default_value of the node.  Default is typically the existing value.  Therefore, a submit handler can ignore form_state[input] and have the benefits of drupal in just the form_state[values] array.
[Input vs Values](https://www.drupal.org/node/1250172)

Comment: I edited the question to reflect search progress. You'll see that `form_state['values']` is not faulty. Data is present there, no need to load the node. I'm a bit lost...

Comment: Good effort so far.  My solution2 answer originally was going to be load the node, loop through form_state['values'] and add any changes to the node, then node_save.  However, because of the field differences I decided to trace the node.module's form save and found that field_attach_submit function is how drupal core does it.  I have not traced the code in panel manager to see how it would differ.

Comment: Maybe, if you have a few min more to edit your sol2, playing with `form_state['values']` & `form_state['input']` as per my edit, and make it a bit more clear for my poor mind, I can try it. What is strange moreover is that not all values are emptied, but they aren't displayed anymore ! this is really confusing

Comment: Another thought that just occured to me, what url are you taken to after save?

Comment: Same behaviour as `node/%node/edit`, after submitting on `node/%node/photos` or others, redirect to `node/%node`. I insist that what is confusing is that not all values are emptied, but they aren't displayed anymore :(... other confusing point is that `form_state[values]` contain the correct data...

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be solved using [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) and [Node Form Panes](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_form_panes) modules, also we need to enable "Page manager" module from [Ctools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools).

1. Open "Page manager" administration page(admin/structure/pages) and click on "Add custom page" link
   [image]
2. Insert basic settings for new page
   [image]
3. Set Context argument
   [image]
   [image]
4. Add access settings
5. Add menu settings
   [image]
6. Choose node type
   [image]
   [image]
7. Choose needed layout
   [image]
8. Add needed fields
   [image]
   [image]
9. Add "Save button"
   [image]
   [image]
   The result should be like this
   [image]

Comment: thanks. I installed that module and used the new field form summary from it, but this changes nothing to that issue. When you save the form, data from fields not called in that form don't show up anymore. Please try with your own content type, and tell me if it makes any difference with the issue I expose. If you put only one field in the panel form, does the node still displays correctly all its data after saving it?

Comment: You can test my settings here https://dkyi.ply.st/node/1. User: drupal, pass: drupal

Comment: Thanks for your efforts ! For tests purposes, I added another text field to your article  content type. Make a test : edit node 1, add text to that field and an image, submit. Then go to edit-body tab, submit => new text and image are gone. This is my issue. Sorry, but that module doesn't solve that form API problem. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Yes. It seems that Node Form Panes  module doesn't support some field types. But you can add your custom validate function for the node form and set value for these fields there. If you won't find better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Almost the Graal for that feature, [Flexiform](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexiform) project has an Edit Panels Pane display:

> Edit an entity using a form embedded in a panel where the base entity
>   is loaded from the panel context.

Just follow these steps :

1. Add new custom pages in `admin/structure/pages`, with paths `/node/%node/foo`, `/node/%node/bar` and so on
2. With selection rule *node ID is from foo_type*
3. Define its menu as local menu tab
4. Create some **flexiforms**, with the fields you wish to
5. Instead of adding separate fields, add your flexiforms as pane contents

This saves correctly the nodes now, even with a few fields in each form. Only some complex fields such as *Inline entity form/Multiple values* are buggy...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it in code, you should consider using [MSNF module](https://www.drupal.org/project/msnf)

> For each step you can define which fields should be included in this
>   step. "Fields" includes core-fields like "Title", "Body" or "Authoring
>   information" as well as fields defined by other modules

You can also consider using [Field Group Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) if you need simplicity.

> Fieldgroup will, as the name implies, group fields together. All
>   fieldable entities will have the possibility to add groups to wrap
>   their fields together. Fieldgroup comes with default HTML wrappers
>   like vertical tabs, horizontal tabs, accordions, fieldsets or div
>   wrappers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm afraid it doesn't fit my need. I'm looking for a way to split node edition in **different pages** accessible by tabs, in order to **reduce loading charge**, not steps or tabs within a same page. I already wrapped fields together in a handmade version with a bit of JQuery. I also tried the _fieldgroup multipages_ display, but none is a solution to load fields as wished.

Comment: Field group vertical tabs was my first thought also; good thinking Gokul.

Comment: Fieldgroup would be perfect if I could ajaxify its tabs. There is Field Group Ajaxified Multipage project, but only for multi step forms...