# Get custom field of node in frontend as its type

Tags: 7

I have a requirement in drupal. In this i have a content type 'sports' and created some custom fields of type dropdown, checkbox and file.

I want to get the custom field with its type as html in front end.

Example In dropdown i have

```
<select>
<options value="15">Cricket</options>
<options value="16">Football</options>
<options value="16">Basketball</options>
</select>
```

I want the same in frontend to display as html

Comment: What is the reason you want to have that options in frontend? You had a form to contains that options?

Comment: Yes i am creating front end form to give as api to create node

Comment: Are you using API form?

Comment: exactly you are right!

Comment: Did you see the output?

Comment: Do you mean your answer? I saw it. It is one of the option to make that.

Comment: But is it possible to get only for specific field as html from all fields

Comment: I can't think of an easy way to do that. You can take a look the approaches stated in this [post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82272/is-there-an-equivalent-of-view-modes-for-form-editing)

Comment: ok thanks for your help and i will look at that.:)

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found what i want actually in front end.

The below code displays the form that it has on backend.

This form is for 'sports' content type. This wil bring all fields with its widget wherever we calling.

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages'); 
$form = node_add('sports');
print drupal_render($form);
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain the code you include in this answer. That will reduce the risk the answer gets deleted (via moderation) because it may be perceived as a low quality answer.